# Free Boson on Torus - Partition function

Tags: conformal-field-theory, regularization

I am currently reading Section 10.2 of the Yellow book by Francesco et al. They have shown in Equation 10.16 that
\begin{equation}
Z_{bos}(\tau) = \sqrt{A} \   \prod_{n} \left (\frac {2\pi}{\lambda_n}\right )^{1/2}
\end{equation}
where $\lambda_n \neq 0$. From now we will ignore the $2\pi$ term in the numerator. To calculate this, the book says we use Zeta function regularization technique. They define
\begin{equation}
G(s) = \sum_{n} ' \frac{1}{\lambda^s_n}
\end{equation}
where prime sum means that $\forall n, \lambda_n \neq 0 $. As it is clear, at $s = 0$, $G(s)$ is not properly defined so we have to analytically continue to lower value of $s$. However, the book says in Equation 10.18 that
\begin{equation}
Z_{bos}(\tau) = \sqrt{A} \exp\left(\frac{1}{2}G'(0) \right)
\end{equation}
I am not sure how they arrived at this conclusion.

Comment: Do you know how to differentiate?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note that:
\begin{equation}
G'(s)=-\sum_n ' \ln( \lambda_n)\times e^{-s\,\ln(\lambda_n)}
\end{equation}
Then you have trivially:
\begin{align}
Z_\text{bos.}&=\sqrt{A}\, \left.\exp \left( \frac{1}{2}G'(s)\right)\right|_{s=0}
\\
&=\sqrt{A} \exp \left( \frac{1}{2}G'(0)\right)
\end{align}